# Are there disadvantages to leaving forest/jungle tiles?

Tags: civilization-5

I started playing a game with the "automated workers remove features" set so that my forests/jungles won't be removed.  Aside from missing out on the production bonus of chopping them down, is there any disadvantage to leaving forest or jungle tiles?

Comment: Why would you leave them rather than improving them? You can build lumber mills on forests and trading posts on jungle tiles.

Comment: Some civilizations (Celts) and some religions receive bonuses from forests, and jungles can provide bonus science with the right buildings.

Comment: @TimFountain - Neither lumber mills nor trading posts remove the underlying feature (jungle/forest/marsh).

Comment: Ahh, I see.  There's also the advantage of generating production by clearing them (useful very early game) or clearing them to build a different improvement (ex: farms).  Since lumber mills/trading posts aren't starting technologies, these aren't always options.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Forests

It's mostly about what you want your city to get. Is your city already surrounded by hills, giving it ample production? A farm is a good candidate to replace the forest, especially if it's over grasslands. If you need production or want gold, however, leaving the forest in place is a better idea, for either a lumber mill or a trading post.

Regarding forests on hills - it's probably better to replace them with mines. You get a little less food but it's better when you try to focus your city on production. Also the production boost from cutting down a forest is useful in the early game.

#### Jungles

Jungles are generally a "bad" tile - like tundra - but in my personal opinion, up until the late game it's worth leaving them for the science boost they give once you get a university. Just make sure you leave enough production and food tiles available to the city.

Once your science per turn is in the hundreds, though, you might consider removing them.

Comment: Great answer +1, I would also like to add that often times jungle/forest terrain can be used for very significant tactical advantage (or disadvantage) in battles.  Leaving a line of forest/jungle for an enemy to have to bring his army through gives you time.  Also, some civilizations like the celts get large bonus from leaving forest/jungle.

Comment: And leaving these features adjacent to cities gives cover to attacking enemies. If you expect to be under siege, you may want to remove those.